# how to create a progress bar that moves back and forth in jface

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Eclipse Platform
Version: 4.25
The code I am currently using is as follows

```
 ModalContext.run(new IRunnableWithProgress() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                                pMonitor = monitor;
                            }

                        }, false, statusLine.getProgressMonitor(), Display.getCurrent());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mzeI.png)
But I found that calling this method multiple times will cause the progress bar to get stuck.

I want to know how to create such a progress bar correctly

Comment: You have to put all the code that uses the progress monitor inside the `run` method and call `monitor.worked` to update the progress as well as `beginTask` to start and `done` to finish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You provided me with a solution to the problem, and I should search for the problem in the pMonitor.begintask()